# Confuse about feathersjs service vs hooks

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I'm new to feathersjs. Please help me understand these bits

So, I have this codes (products.services.js)

```
function mapUserIdToData(context) {
  if (context.data && context.params.route.userId) {
    context.data.user = context.params.route.userId;
  }
}

app.use("/stores", new Stores(options, app));
const service = app.service("stores");
service.hooks(hooks);

// setup our nested routes
app.use("/users/:userId/stores", app.service("stores"));
app.service("users/:userId/stores").hooks({
    before: {
      find(context) {
        if (context.params.route.userId)
          context.params.query.user = context.params.route.userId;
      },
      create: mapUserIdToData,
      update: mapUserIdToData,
      patch: mapUserIdToData,
    },
});
```

And in my register module (register.service.js), I called these logic to create store for new user

```
const users = this.app.service("users");
const user = await users.create(userData);
// save store
if (storeTitle) {
  const stores = this.app.service("stores");
  await stores.create({ user: user._id, title: storeTitle });
}
```

What I don't understand is : Why the line `await stores.create({ user: user._id, title: storeTitle });` also trigger hooks logic in `app.service("users/:userId/stores")` ? I know because it run the `mapUserIdToData` function, which will be failed because there is no route param for `userId`.

Thank You

Comment: Hmm it works if I change this `app.use("/users/:userId/stores", app.service("stores"));` to `app.use("/users/:userId/stores", new Stores(options, app));`

Comment: I would recommend using the feathers cli to create your project. The folder structure created there is better organized and should help you understand how services are structured. https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/generator.html